# angular2 select does not choose populated vale as default

Tags: select, angular

I have a select field that is populated by ngModel on ngOnChanges.

```
<label for="selectNumerator">Numerator:</label>
    <select class="form-control select" [ngModel]="numeratorSelect" (ngModelChange)="onNumeratorChange($event)" name="selectNumerator">
        <option *ngFor="let x of numeratorSelect" value="{{x.optionId}}">{{x.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

However, after the page loads and the data is added, the select field is blank by default. Data below that is being added to the select

```
[{"name":"dataname","optionId":1,"factor":4,"description":null}]
```

How do I set it so that the select box will show the first option in the list?

Happy to provide more info if necessary.

Comment: What is the "populated value"? What's the value of `numeratorSelect`?

Comment: So, I would push the name and optionId from the provided array into a select option. In this instance the data (dataname) is available when i click on the dropdown but the select appears empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a seperate variable holding the currently selected value:

```ts
export class ComponentA {
    numeratorSelect: Array<any> = [
        { 
            name: "dataname", 
            optionId: 1, 
            factor: 4, 
            description: null
        }
    ];
    selectedOption: number = numeratorSelect[0].optionId;
```

And in your template bind to it in the `ngModel`:

```html
<label for="selectNumerator">Numerator:</label>
<select class="form-control select" [ngModel]="selectedOption" (ngModelChange)="onNumeratorChange($event)" name="selectNumerator">
    <option *ngFor="let x of numeratorSelect" value="{{x.optionId}}">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
[ngModel]="numeratorSelect"
```

and

```
<option *ngFor="let x of numeratorSelect"
```

doesn't really make sense.

```
[ngModel]="..."
```

needs to refer to a value that matches one of

```
value="{{x.optionId}}"
```

like

```
[ngModel]="selectedNumerator"
```

```
selectedNumerator = 1;
```